# Unexpected currency symbol in currency NumberFormat

Tags: java, android, internationalization, currency

While testing on an Android emulator, I came across an inconsistency between the formatted strings produced by a NumberFormat instance and it's reported currency symbol.

I start by setting up a localized currency formatter like so:

```
// displayLocale is af_NA
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) 
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(displayLocale);

// currency is USD
df.setCurrency(currency); // USD localized for af_NA
```

Then I use it to format a value.  The result of invoking:

`df.format(1)`

is "$1".  This might not seem obviously wrong, but when I check the details of the formatter, things dont add up.  Invoking:

`df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getCurrencySymbol()`

yields "USD" and not the expected "$"...what!?  Even stranger, I've yet to find a physical device that I can replicate the issue on.  Tests running under Robolectric don't exhibit this behavior either.

Has anybody else come across this behavior before and if so, any idea what's causing it?  And finally, is this behavior that might be encountered on physical devices or is it purely an AVD thing?

UPDATE:

Here's a method you can call from any Activity to check for and print out any offending formatters:

```
void checkFormatters() {
        Currency USD = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);
        Money oneDollar = new Money(BigDecimal.ONE, USD);

        for(Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
            df.setCurrency(USD);
            String currencySymbol = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getCurrencySymbol();
            String localizedDollarString = CurrencyUtils.getPrettyCurrencyString(locale, oneDollar);
            if(!localizedDollarString.contains(currencySymbol)) {
                Log.w(TAG, locale.getDisplayName() + ": Expected localized dollar string [" + localizedDollarString +
                        "] to contain currency symbol [" + currencySymbol +
                        "]");
            }
        }
    }
```

If the device you're testing on has the issue then you'll see results like these:

```
Uzbek (LATN): Expected localized dollar string [$ 1] to contain currency symbol: [US$]
Uzbek (Uzbekistan,UZ): Expected localized dollar string [$ 1] to contain currency symbol: [US$]
```

Comment: Can you please show how you are initializing `displayLocale` and `currency`. `df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getCurrencySymbol()` works right for me.

Comment: I'm am using `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` and testing all available.  Many (but not all) of the African locales have this issue.  My Currency init code is `Currency.getInstance(Locale.US)`.  Again, I've only been able to replicate the issue on an emulator.

Comment: also the target for my AVD that demonstrates the issue is: Google APIs (x86 System Image) (API level 19)

Comment: How are you initializing and assigning `displayLocale`. I tried using african currency in netbeans and I did not have issues.

Comment: Like I said, I loop through and test all available locales - I don't explicitly initialize a particular one. My use of the Locale instance is documented in it's entirety above.  I would not expect you to be able to replicate the issue in Netbeans since I cannot replicate the issue in my own unit tests or on any device except for the specific emulator detailed above.